# Azure Storage Emulator Error Accessing Blobs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, azure, azure-storage

Just noticed a strange issue.  I can no longer access the blobs (iamge files) that are stored in my Azure Storage Emulator.  First noticed that my web role wasn't serving up my files from emulator when running in debug.  I tried to access files using a third party app, cloudberry.  cloudberry lets me browse the storage emulator container that I created, but when I try to access a file it fails.  Both my app and cloudberry fail with

> 500 error

returned... not helpful.

Tried restarting storage emulator, no luck.  Tried starting emulator from Azure SDK command prompt to see if there was an error.  started successfully...  no error reported, but still having my issue when i try and access my blobs.  I have SQL Express installed and I verified that MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS service is running.  I have made no recent changes to my web role configurations.  I am using Azure Tools version: June 2012.  Anyone have ideas on what else I should try?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the size of the development storage database? If it is larger than (or close to) 2Gb, the issue might be from that.

Comment: thanks for your help.  pretty sure that's not it since i don't have much in there.  I'll check it anyway though. How do i do that?

Comment: Another thing you could do is enable logging for storage emulator service. Please see my answer here on MSDN Forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/99e2014d-590d-4ec4-88ef-b3623ce44fe9/. However just be careful as there are really verbose logs so after you have found the issue just turn the logging off.

Comment: Don't have AppData, do I have App_Data.  It's empty.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: AppData folder would be under your local user's account. So the directory would be "C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\DevelopmentStorage". Also the "AppData" folder may not be visible by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is also discussed in this SO thread:

[Mysterious disappearing Azure development storage assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252499/mysterious-disappearing-azure-development-storage-assets)

In my experience, I've got this problem only the emulators that ships with Azure SDK 1.7 . As you can see from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13731286/753737), the problem disappears by using the updated emulator in Azure SDK 1.8 (I've used it for more than 4 months) -- you can upgrade it while continuing to use 1.7 libraries in your cloud projects.

Answer (score 1):

Gaurav Mantri's comments were helpful for tracking down my error.  Examining the error log I found that I'm experiencing a somewhat common issue where my azure storage corrupts itself.  I found a informative but inconclusive forum thread on it (link below) if someone is looking for help on the same or similar issues.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/699d8861-b3d3-4140-9cf3-b749a2cfed39/